# French expression for "uncorrected proof"

Tags: traduction, anglais

Uncorrected proofs are Articles in Press that have been copy-edited and formatted, but have not been finalized yet. They still need to be proof-read and corrected by the author(s) and the text could still change before final publication.

https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22802/supporthub/sciencedirect/

What is the French counterpart term or expression for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il est apparent que c'est le terme de langue anglaise « uncorrected proof » qui soit utilisé dans le monde scientifique de langue française. Tout au moins on le trouvera en filigrane sur les articles.

Deux exemples (*Il en existe d'autres.*)

1/ [image]

2/ UNCORRECTED PROOF - Paris School of Economics

Cependant, le terme semble avoir une traduction et celle-ci est « [épreuves non-corrigées](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/the+uncorrected+proofs) » (reverso).

Answer (score 1):

There might be a dedicated expression, otherwise I would suggest:

> Ébauche finale.